# How to check if specific version of IBM i supports Fully free RPG?

Tags: rpgle

V7R1M0 is the version I see in spool files generated in the IBM i server used in my company. Does this version support fully free RPG flavor where even F and D specs can be written in free format? How can this be found out? I have copy pasted few of fully free code samples the available on the internet and it gets highlighted in error which suggests it doesn't work.

Please note that no RDI is available in my company. So this was done in SEU. I have researched a lot about this but there is no definitive guide that can confirm this point

Comment: Honestly, if you are continuing to do development on IBM i, the company will need to invest in RDi. SEU is all but dead. The last I heard, it will remain in the OS for a while, but they aren't improving it nor adding support for future features.

However, RPG will still compile it, so you can continue to use SEU, but you won't know if you have syntax errors until you compile making you less efficient.

Comment: You need to use RDi! With Fully free rpg you can start coding at column 1. If you want to open your code in SEU, it will cut the first 8 columns of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SEU does not now nor will it ever support anything released after v6.1. If you want to use features of RPG released in the last 7 years you either have to turn off syntax validation in SEU, or use RDi. There are other options of course, see [What is the best IDE to use for programming in RPGILE for the AS/400 ? Can you connect to a 400 using Visual Studios IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44116062/2296441) for more info. Note that only RDi is guaranteed to support the most recent RPG developments. Third party editors may lag behind while developers determine how to support new features. In addition, some of these editors only support source code in the IFS.

Comment: In other words, the SEU syntax checker is frozen at v6.1.  So it will highlight all the newer functionality as being in error.  You can ignore it and it will successfully compile (assuming you have the PTFs needed for 7.1)