# GUI for RPGLE Webservice Development on iseries OS V7R1

Tags: web-services, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am researching the best GUI interface to deploy to developer laptop(s) to develop and deploy RPGLE webservice processes on an iseries currently running OS V7R1.

We have future plans to migrate to OS V7R2 or V7R3 but are currently limited to the scope of the V7R1.

Known options: Websphere, i navigator, rdp .......

Have not used any of these to develop webservices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best IDE to use for programming in RPGILE for the AS/400 ? Can you connect to a 400 using Visual Studios IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114511/what-is-the-best-ide-to-use-for-programming-in-rpgile-for-the-as-400-can-you-c)

Answer (score 0):

I worked with two webservice frameworks in RPG until now.

- [Here you can find an OSS-Framework similar to javax servlets](https://github.com/sitemule/ILEastic)
- [Here you can find information about the IWS for IBMi developed by IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/integrated-web-services-ibm-i-web-services-)